# TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null How to solve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

```
const ref = useRef(null);

const executeScroll = () => {
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        executeScroll()
    }, [])


<div className="comment" ref={ref}>
//Data
</div>
```

I am trying to go to a particular div. I got this error. Any idea why is this error is showing or how to solve it?

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null"

Answer (score 2):

When the `useEffect` runs, the `div` hasn't mounted to the DOM yet so the `ref` is still `null`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (ref.current) {
    executeScroll();
  }
}, [ref.current])
```

Comment: If I use ref={ref} in a child component It will work or not?

Comment: Yes, it will work just fine, replace your `useEffect` code with what I posted above.